# Deserialize binary serialized instances from third party DLL gives uninitialized/empty instance

Tags: c#, properties, deserialization

I have a collection of files containing binary serialized instances of a class from a third party dll. I don't have access to the third party source code but I have the dll. I need to deserialize these files into instances of the class.

I simply do this:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(@"C:\my\path", FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
ThirdPartyType o = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream) as ThirdPartyType;
stream.Close();
```

This gives no errors. When I run the project in debug mode and put a breakpoint after deserialization I can inspect the instance `o`. All members of `o` are `null` or `0` so the instance was created but no members were initialized to the correct values.

I have tried decompiling the dll (with .Net Reflector) and inserted a breakpoint in the following place:

```
protected ThirdPartyType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {}
```

Now I can inspect the argument `info` and here I can see that the members `m_types`, `m_members` & `m_data` are set to the correct values that I expect from the serialized file. However, for some reason the constructor won't make use of this and initialize the instance correctly. I can only see this constructor header, the decompile won't show me the code for it.

To take control over the initialization myself I created a local subclass of the class:

```
[Serializable]
public class FakeThirdPartyType : ThirdPartyType
{
    protected FakeThirdPartyType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        int width = info.GetInt32("clientWidth");
        this.ClientWidth = width;
        //Many other properties as well...
    }
}
```

And then I bind my `BinaryFormatter` to a `SerializationBinder` that returns `FakeThirdPartyType` when asked for `ThirdPartyType` (and the correct type for any other call). Now I get to my deserialization constructor when I run it. But here I have a really strange problem. I can see that `width` gets assigned the correct value (`!=0`), but after the next row `this.ClientWidth` is still `0`. Same result with:

```
base.GetType().GetProperty("ClientWidth").SetValue(this, width, null);
```

Might there be anything I'm doing wrong? Is it likely that the problems I'm experiencing is caused by cross assembly deserialization? Is it likely that the error lies in the third party code that I can't access? It seems that the setters for the properties does not work (at least don't affect the same variables as the getters return).

During debugging I can inspect the `ThirdPartyType` type and see that it has the private field `_clientWidth` but I can't find any way to set that directly.

Comment: What other constructors does the 3rd party type have? Also, how have the values in it been set if the property setters don't work (special set methods/passed in to ctor/calculated from other properties/etc)?

Comment: I also tried **base(null, context)** and this throws no error so I suspect that the original constructor is simply empty and the original implementer did not mean for it to be deserialized. Very strange since they provide me with a set of their serialized objects.

Comment: @mlorbetske: Only one where the only argument is an System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: @mlorbetske: I don't know how the values get there in the first place. I only have the serialized versions and there they are correctly set. Maybe the problem is elsewhere, like in my dll reference. But I think I have the correct version. It matches the version in the serialized file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some decompile the properties for the class all look like this:

```
    public int Property
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public Object Property2
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is of course what causes all values to be null and 0 after deserialization. Why these properties are like this is a mystery though. But that is not in the scope of this question.